# Autowired doesn't work for RESTEasy and Spring 3

Tags: spring, jax-rs, resteasy, autowired

I have a trouble with using @Autowired with RESTEasy 2.2.1.GA and Spring 3.0.5.RELEASE. I always get an NPE at

```
String result = customerBo.getMsg();
```

into my service.

How to correct autowired behavior for my code?

This is my RESTEasy service:

```
@Component
@Path("/api")
public class Rest {

    @Autowired
    CustomerBo customerBo;

      @GET
      @Produces("text/plain")
      public String getXMLMessage() {
              String result = customerBo.getMsg();
              return result;
      }
}
```

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- JBoss RESTEasy -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>ua.softserve.hotel.api.Rest</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- JBoss RESTEasy end -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

And this is my root-context.xml:

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context:   -->

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="customerBo" class="ua.softserve.hotel.api.CustomerBoImpl">
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="ua.softserve.hotel" />

    <import resource="data.xml" />
    <import resource="security.xml" />

</beans>
```

Comment: could you post your web.xml corrected?

Comment: You shouldn't wait a lot from it. It was a study project, so it still can contain errors. The last version placed here: https://github.com/kateryna1118/hotel07/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

Comment: I have done as like you commenting that line code 
`<!-- Commented because of concurrent with RESTEasy's listener -->
<!-- listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener-->` but that is right way?

Comment: Yep, *RESTEasy* uses its own `org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem solved.
The problem was that for the implementation I used articles from different sources for different versions of libraries.

The correct answer to my question I found in official documentation:
http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.2.1.GA/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Spring_Integration.html

Comment: May I know how have you resolved this ? Actually, I could not use **Autowired**. I have to rely on getting the bean instance using  applicaton's context.

Comment: I think in your case you better to create new question. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation,  The SpringContextLoaderListener must be declared after ResteasyBootstrap as it uses ServletContext attributes initialized by it.

org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap

org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener